# Postgresql Suggest Indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-8.4

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, when you run SHOWPLAN on a query, it will sometimes tell you what indexes you should create in order to speed up the query.

I am using Postgresql, and can't see to figure out what indexes to create. Does anyone know of a way to do this in Postgresql 8.4? Or some other 3rd-party software that will?

Comment: seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318727/postgresql-index-usage-analysis

Comment: Don't know of anything that will do this automatically (hard to imagine that working well in non-trivial cases). I'm sure if you post the query you'll get some suggestions. Out of curiosity, why such an old version of PG?

Comment: It's the default version with RHEL 6.4. I suppose there are non-RHEL repositories I could use to get a newer version, but that requires upgrade, and it's a production machine, etc. Why do you ask?